# For loop integer AND string variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, for-loop, integer

Can someone tell me how I can change the values of x and y to '*' and '.'? Making the variables string doesn't help because I need N to be an integer as it is user input, and will conflict in loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nvalue
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x, y, N;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Value of N : ");
    N = keyboard.nextInt();

    for(x=2; x<=N; x++)
    {
        for(y=1; y<=5; y++)
        {
         System.out.println(y +" * "+ x + " = " + (x*y));
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }
}
}
```

Basically I need it to output this:

```
* * * * * * 
. * * * * *
. . * * * *
. . . * * *
. . . . * *
. . . . . *
```

Comment: to * and . under what criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
     System.out.print(".");
  }

  for (int j = i; j < N; ++j) {
     System.out.print("*");
  }

  System.out.println(); // Next line
}
```

Note the use of `print` and not `println` for printing without a line break.

Comment: You can even change the second for loop to `for (; j < N; ++j) {`, because as of the beginning of that loop, `j` is _already_ equal to `N`.

Comment: @Widdershins not true, j is visible only in the for block

Comment: Well that's easy, just replace the first `for` block with `int j = 0; for (; j < i; ++j) {`. This is still a very fast and clean way of doing it.

Comment: I'm sure this is all extremely negligible in impact and will save approximately 1 cpu cycle per row drawn, but it's still more elegant. In my book, if you can make it _any_ faster without making it look way worse, there's no reason not to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(x=0; x<N; x++){
    String ln = "";
    for(y=0; y<5; y++){
       ln += (y < x) ? "* " : ". ";
    }
    System.out.println(ln);
}
```

Comment: It's the trinary comparison operator - essentially a way to put an if into one statement.

Comment: now i understand. its not as complicated as looks lol. if y<x print "*", else print "." ... Boolean-ish. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(x=1; x<=N; x++)
{
    for(y=1; y<=5; y++)
    {
      if (y >= x) {
         System.out.print(" * ");
      } else {
         System.out.print(" . ");
      }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x, y, N;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Value of N : ");
    N = keyboard.nextInt();

    for(x=0; x<N; x++)
    {
        for(y=0; y<N; y++)
        {
            if (y >= x)    {
                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" . ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
for(int x=0; x<N; x++){
  for(int y=0; y<N;y++){
   if(y<x){
      System.out.print(".");
    }else{
      System.out.print("*");
    }
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Damn, someone posted the same answer above me.